# Can not deserialize JSON with json string inside

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a json like below. The x's are there to omit sensitive data

```
{"errormessage":"{\"timestamp\":\"2021-10- 19T07:57:35.205+0000\",\"status\":400,\"error\":\ "Bad Request\",\"message\":\"Bad Request: xxxx xxx xxx xxx xxx. path\u003d/xxx/verify\",\"path\":\"/xxx /xxx\"}"}
```

I am trying to deserialize this json into the class below

```
public class TransferResponse {

 private Optional<String> timeStamp = Optional.empty();
 private Optional<String> status = Optional.empty();
 private Optional<String> error = Optional.empty();

 @JsonAlias(value = {"errorMessage", "errormessage"})
 private Optional<String> message = Optional.empty();
 private Optional<String> path = Optional.empty();

}
```

They way I am trying to deserialize it is given below

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());

final String nestedErrorResponse = "{\"errormessage\":\"{\"timestamp\":\"2021-10- 19T07:57:35.205+0000\",\"status\":400,\"error\":\"Bad Request\",\"message\":\"Bad Request: xxxx xx is xx xxx. path\u003d/xxx/xxx\",\"path\":\"/xxxx /xxx\"}\"}";

TransferResponse responseObject = objectMapper.readValue(nestedErrorResponse, TransferResponse.class);
```

But I am getting an exception like below

```
Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (String)"{"errormessage":"{"timestamp":"2021-10- 19T07:57:35.205+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Bad Request: xxxx xx is xx xxx. path=/xxxxx/verify","path":"/xxxxx /xxxxx"}"}"; line: 1, column: 21]
```

I want to be able to read the value against errormessage as string. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the slashes when you provide a json string with nested json programatically - add a slash and escape it at once, that makes nested quotes have 3 slashes:

```
final String nestedErrorResponse = "{\"errormessage\":\"{\\\"timestamp\\\":\\\"2021-10- 19T07:57:35.205+0000\\\",\\\"status\\\":400,\\\"error\\\":\\\"Bad Request\\\",\"message\\\":\\\"Bad Request: xxxx xx is xx xxx. path\u003d/xxx/xxx\\\",\\\"path\":\\\"/xxxx /xxx\\\"}\"}";
```

I use Intellij Idea and whrn I copy a json string into another string, it adds the proper number of slashes automatically.

Comment: I figured it out later. Did not know about the 3 slashes thing earlier. Learning something new everyday :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert your JSON data as shown below and test your code, hopefully, this will help you to fix the issue. I usually test my JSON data in online Json data validator t. ex https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

```
   "errormessage":{
      "timestamp":"2021-10- 19T07:57:35.205+0000",
      "status":400,
      "error":"Bad Request",
      "message":"Bad Request: xxxx xxx xxx xxx xxx. path\\\u003d/xxx/verify",
      "path":"/xxx /xxx"
   }
```